# MotoDev Says I Have Errors, but it won't show me them

Tags: android, eclipse

This is a really stupid question I imagine, but is there a way to search for hidden errors.  I'm working on a project in MotoDev's Eclipse environment, and it won't let me run suddenly stating that I need to fix errors first, but it won't show any errors in the log at all.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `Problem` view, you may get something there.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any hidden errors in MOTODEV Studio.  As Tony mentions, bring up the Problem view to see if there are any errors listed there.  Also, look in the project explorer and see if there are any files or folders with a red X on them, which indicates a file with a problem is in there.  Failing that, do a clean build on the project.

If the problems persist, give us a shout on the MOTODEV forums and we'll work with you to get the issue resolved.

Eric